# Redshift problem with getdate() being cached across multiple procedure calls

Tags: stored-procedures, timestamp, amazon-redshift

I would like have timestamp along execution of a procedure, im using GETDATE() but calling procedure a 2nd, 3rd etc times, keeps returning same timestamps, seems redshift doing some sort of caching on GETDATE() ?

OK - getdate() outside procedure, correctly keeps returning different timestamps:

```
select getdate();
2021-03-09 13:03:18.0
select getdate();
2021-03-09 13:03:26.0
```

NOK - now will create test procedure, capturing start and end timestamps (and big FOR loop to make a pause), and call procedure more then 1 time, and I see on same start/end values being returned on 2nd, 3rd executions etc.

```
create or replace procedure tests.test_getdate_cache()
as $$ 
declare
    ts  timestamp;
    f   float;
begin
--    execute 'SET enable_result_cache_for_session TO OFF';
    
    ts:= getdate();
    raise info 'START - getdate()=[%]', ts;

    FOR i IN 1..10000000 LOOP
--        ts:= getdate();
--        raise info '**loop[%]  getdate()=[%]', i, ts;
        f:= i * 1234.4234;
    END LOOP;
    
    ts:= getdate();
    raise info 'END - getdate()=[%]', ts;

--    execute 'SET enable_result_cache_for_session TO ON';
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
/

call tests.test_getdate_cache();
START - getdate()=[2021-03-09 13:15:47]
END - getdate()=[2021-03-09 13:16:00

START - getdate()=[2021-03-09 13:15:47]       <---- DUPLICATED VALUE
END - getdate()=[2021-03-09 13:16:00]         <---- DUPLICATED VALUE

--cache results off
START - getdate()=[2021-03-09 13:23:22]
END - getdate()=[2021-03-09 13:23:34]

START - getdate()=[2021-03-09 13:23:22]       <---- DUPLICATED VALUE
END - getdate()=[2021-03-09 13:23:34]         <---- DUPLICATED VALUE


SELECT * FROM svl_stored_proc_messages WHERE 1=1 ORDER BY recordtime desc limit 4
userid | session_userid | pid   | xid     | query | recordtime          | loglevel | loglevel_text | message                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          | linenum | querytxt                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             | label                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            | aborted
-------+----------------+-------+---------+-------+---------------------+----------+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------
   101 |            101 | 31870 | 1540358 |  4332 | 2021-03-09 13:16:32 |       30 | INFO          | END - getdate()=[2021-03-09 13:16:00]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |      16 | call tests.test_getdate_cache()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      | default                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |       0
   101 |            101 | 31870 | 1540358 |  4332 | 2021-03-09 13:16:19 |       30 | INFO          | START - getdate()=[2021-03-09 13:15:47]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |       7 | call tests.test_getdate_cache()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      | default                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |       0

   101 |            101 | 31870 | 1540334 |  4325 | 2021-03-09 13:16:00 |       30 | INFO          | END - getdate()=[2021-03-09 13:16:00]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |      16 | call tests.test_getdate_cache()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      | default                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |       0
   101 |            101 | 31870 | 1540334 |  4325 | 2021-03-09 13:15:47 |       30 | INFO          | START - getdate()=[2021-03-09 13:15:47]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |       7 | call tests.test_getdate_cache()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      | default                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |       0
\
```

I even tried to turn off result cache, despite probably thats only for SELECTs while getdate() is function, but, anyway gave it a try, but same result, timestamps keep coming the same. Just uncomment the above lines
--    execute 'SET enable_result_cache_for_session TO OFF';
--    execute 'SET enable_result_cache_for_session TO ON';

Any idea how can I get fresh timestamps early in procedure and when about to exit ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was also interested in getting a datetime for the current statement and I ran into the same issues you did with getdate().  This worked for me:

```
cast(timeofday() as timestamp)
```

It feels like a hack, but I'm going forward with this for my Redshift procedure logging.

Comment: I no longer work with Redshift -neither do I again- but thanks for sharing, I'm not able to test it, so you saying that calling my test procedure without your "hack" :) 
`cast(timeofday() as timestamp)`
above would show different timestamps START/END for each time procedure tests.test_getdate_cache() called ?

Answer (score 0):

Getdate() returns the current statement time and since a stored procedure call is a single statement it will return the same time throughout the procedure.  See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/Date_functions_header.html

I don't think what you are trying to do can work (reliably).  Remember Redshift is a cluster of networked computers and while their clocks are sync'ed this isn't perfect.  Each node will have a slightly different clock and the network time to talk to each other will also affect comparisons.  You procedure isn't running in one place but many.  You likely can get at the real time of each node through the use of a python UDF but then you have to sort out what it is you are seeing from the disparate results.  This may be doable for single calls to the UDF but when you apply the process to real data stored across many nodes you are likely to see many conflicting answers.